# Test b-form-radio with vue-test and Jest

Tags: jestjs, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils

When using the

```
const radio = wrapper.find("input[type='radio'");
radio.setChecked();
await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
```

throes:
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of null"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
radio.setChecked()
```

use

```
radio.trigger('click')
```

It seems that bootstrap-vue don't use the native HTML radio event.